# Test Case failing on on_initialize hook!

Tags: polkadot, pallet, substrate-node-template

I'm writing a test case for the on_initalize hook!

```
    #[pallet::hooks]
    impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
        fn on_initialize(_now: T::BlockNumber) -> Weight {
         
             let time: u64 = T::TimeProvider::now().as_secs() - 180 ;
            
            <RootOracleEvent<T>>::mutate(|event_list| {
                if let Some(index) = event_list.iter().position(|member| member.time_stamp <= time) {
                    event_list.remove(index);
                    
                }
                
            });     
        
                    
            T::DbWeight::get().writes(1)
        }

    
    }
```

And, when I write a test case, its throws an error: ---- tests::valid_weights stdout ----
thread 'tests::valid_weights' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', pallets/pallet_oracle_feed/src/lib.rs:86:29
note: run with the `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

```
#[test]
fn valid_weights() {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_support::weights::RuntimeDbWeight;

    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
      let db_weights: RuntimeDbWeight = <Test as frame_system::Config>::DbWeight::get();
     

        assert_eq!(
            ClubPalletTesting::on_initialize(1),
            db_weights.writes(2));
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you not use the current block number `now`? I have an assumption what could be the cause, but it would help if you could share the code of the `on_initialize` or the whole pallet, if possible.

Comment: No, Im not using the value of 'now' , inside my logic..

Comment: I have updated my code...@OliverTale-Yazdi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. Could be that you are not initializing the block number, it is therefore 0. This can lead to various errors when subtracting from it. You can easily fix this by modifying your `new_test_ext` function to do so. `1` may not be enough in your case.

```rust
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    let mut ext: sp_io::TestExternalities = system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<Test>().unwrap().into();
    ext.execute_with(|| System::set_block_number(1));
    ext
}
```

2. Ensure that the `TimeProvider` is initialized before your pallet. A good example is in [pallet-gilt](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1b1a5e12c0e391c7ed4e3ffa332eb2fe928d257f/frame/gilt/src/mock.rs#L128). I don't know what your time provider does, but it seems to return something less than 180 secs, hence the error.
3. Always use `saturating` or `checked` arithmetic operations in the runtime.
   You can change the code to `let time: u64 = T::TimeProvider::now().as_secs().saturating_sub(180);`.

Comment: 2nd was the issue..

Comment: Okay great! Then please mark this question as solved.